# change admin static url in django

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django app. Recently I have transferred my static files to Rackspace Cloud Files and serving from that. To do this I have changed the `static` url in settings.py as follows

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://somekey.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/static/'
```

And it is working file.

The problem is that now the admin static files are also served from the above (rackspace) url. How can I change to the earlier i.e. `/static/admin/` ?

Basically I want the app static files to be served from cdn and admin files from my site.

My environment:

```
Python 2.7.3
Django 1.4.2
```

Comment: I don't really understand the benefit of separating admin static content, nevertheless, you could set up your server to eavesdrop on static patterns and reroute them accordingly?

Comment: @Hedde I am new to django. I am unable to what you are saying. Can you please elaborate more or provide some example. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the location of static files in personal apps and the django admin frontend all use the value of the STATIC_URL variable, I'd guess it is not possible to serve static content from two different sources.

May I suggest that you upload the static files of your admin frontend to your Rackspace instance? Assuming your Django install is located PATH, all you have to do is upload the content of `PATH/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static` to  `https://somekey.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/static/`.

Another solution would be to not change the value of STATIC_URL: set it to "/static", for instance, and then configure your Apache server to redirect requests to your Rackspace instance:

```
Redirect /static https://somekey.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/static/
Redirect /admin/static https://somekey.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/admin/static/
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been almost 10 years and now I'm facing the same issue. For all the searchers out there, below was my solution (**bonus:** how to serve Django admin static files from a CDN out-of-the box).

I created a custom storage class that takes an additional setting - `STATIC_URL_RULES` - where you can define individual `STATIC_URLs` depending on the static prefix. This was useful to offset all static, unchanged admin CSS and JS calls I had from my server to a CDN. (kudos to the creators of [statically.io](https://statically.io/))

In your settings file:

```py
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'myapp.CustomStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_URL_RULES = [
    ('admin/', f'https://cdn.statically.io/gh/django/django/{django.__version__}/django/contrib/admin/static/'),
]
# All other paths:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The definition of the custom storage class was:

```py
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import StaticFilesStorage
from django.utils.encoding import filepath_to_uri


class CustomStaticFilesStorage(StaticFilesStorage):
    """Allows setting a different STATIC_URL for each static file prefix."""

    def url(self, name):
        for prefix, base_url in settings.STATIC_URL_RULES:
            if name.startswith(prefix):
                # largely based on django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage
                url = filepath_to_uri(name)
                if url is not None:
                    url = url.lstrip('/')
                return urljoin(base_url, url)

        return super().url(name)
```

And this is the result (template vs rendered):

```
{% load static %}
{% static 'myapp/custom.min.css' %}
{% static 'admin/css/responsive.css" %}
```

```
/static/myapp/custom.min.css
https://cdn.statically.io/gh/django/django/3.2.13/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/responsive.css
```

**PS:** Statically.io also lets you add ".min" before the file type and it will minify CSS and JS for you. You may add that snippet to your custom storage class.